# How to count number of letter occurences in multiple strigns simultaneusly using Counter in Python? Is + correct to use?

Tags: python, count, counter

I am trying to count how many times particular letters occur in given strings.
Am I using Counter correctly? The question is can I calculate it from two strings at once using +? It looks like working, but Im not sure if its correct.
Example - to find how many times letters t r u e occur in strings

```
    name1 = input("What is your name? \n")
    name2 = input("What is their name? \n")
    
    from collections import Counter
    
    lowercase_name1 = str.lower(name1)
    lowercase_name2 = str.lower(name2)
    
    cntr_true = Counter(lowercase_name1 + lowercase_name2)
    total_letters_true = cntr_true["t"] + cntr_true["r"] + 
    cntr_true["u"] + cntr_true["e"]

    number = total_letters_true
    print(f"{number}")
```

Result:

```
What is your name? 
True 
What is their name? 
Tr ue
8
```

Comment: What do you expect?  Try to `print(cntr_true)` and confirm it first.

Comment: The reason for your skepticism isn't clear. If `s` and `t` are strings then `s+t` neither creates nor destroys characters. Thus e.g. `Counter(s+t)['a'] == Counter(s)['a'] + Counter(t)['a']`

Comment: I edited code with print function in the end. So he strings I need to check are lowercase_name1 and lowercase_name2. For example they contain word True and True. So count should be 4 and 4. And the number value is correct, but my question is can i code it like this:     cntr_true = Counter(lowercase_name1 + lowercase_name2) by using +, to avoid creating two separate variables cntr_true_name1 and cntr_true_name2

Comment: Can you tell how you want the output

Comment: T:2 time
R: 2 time
U: 2 time
or you want what ever user enter in name1 and name2 it will count occurance of each letter

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
name1 = input("What is your name? \n")
name2 = input("What is their name? \n")
list1=list(str.lower(name1+name2))
res=Counter(list1)
print("Letter Count: ")
for key in res:
    print(key, ':', res[key])
```

This code will count occurance of each letter in name1 and name2
[image]

Below Code will print t r u e occurrence only and exclude rest of letters

```
from collections import Counter
name1 = input("What is your name? \n")
name2 = input("What is their name? \n")
list1=list(str.lower(name1+name2).strip())
res=Counter(list1)
print("Letter Count: ")
t=0
for key in res:
    if key=='t' or key=='r' or key=='u'or key=='e':
        t=t+res[key]
        print(key,':',res[key])
print("Total Counter Value: ",t)
```

Output:
[image]